# popupTable shows same values for every polygon when using multiple layers/columns

Tags: r, leaflet, r-mapview

popupTable works fine with mapview when I use only one column but it stops working when defining multiple zcols, eg. `mapview(map, zcol=c("variable1", "variable2", popup=popupTable(map, zcol=c("column1","column2","column4"))`. For every popup on the map (polygon data) it shows the first entry of the dataset, it seems to disable the links to Feature IDs, as the Feature ID on every popup is 1. Using `mapview(map, zcol="variable1", popup=popupTable(map, zcol=c("column1","column2","column4"))` works just fine.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which version of mapview are you using? Version 2.10.2 on github might already have this fixed. Can you try that?

Comment: I updated to version 2.10.2 (used 2.10) and the problem persists.